# Rails 3 - strftime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strftime

If I have a :due column that is a datetime type, how would I make calling `.strftime` on it work?

For instance, I have

```
<% @todos.each do |todo|%>
   <%= todo.due.strftime("%h %d") %>
<% end %>
```

in my show view and I get *undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass*

I have this in my show method in the controller:

`@todos = ProjectTodo.for_project(params[:id])`

**Note:** I'm not trying to display when it was updated or created, just want to display a formatted date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
 <% @todos.each do |todo|%>
 <%= todo.due ? todo.due.strftime("%h %d") : nil %>
 <% end %>


      If the date is there then it will convert to the given format else it will display nil.
```

Comment: please check whether all the rows in the table having due column with value.

Comment: Not all the rows have a value for the due column.

Comment: then we have to use <%= todo.due ? todo.due.strftime("%h %d") : nil %> this one. it will work.

Comment: Yeah I know it works. But how? does the question mark act as an if/else statement?

Comment: If Condition is true ? Then value X : Otherwise value Y

Comment: a==b ? 10 : 20. in this case if the condition(a equal to b) is true it will display 10. else it will display 20.

Comment: So in our statement, it's saying if todo.due has a value, display it with the strftime modifier, else display nil?